# After moving wordpress to new folder, a specific plugin stopped working

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I had to change my wordpress site to a new place (from subfolder to root) and now, when I try to use a shortcode plugin - vibe shortcodes, it doesn't work.
Normally, the plugin opens a popup window with options to fill and then generate the shortcode. Now it freezes for a while and later on appears a internal page that has nothing to do with the plugin.
I tried to put the shortcode writing directly, but it doesn't work too.

Could someone help me with some idea about what's happening?
I already replaced the paths in database, by the way...

Comment: I enabled debug mode for wordpress and now I'm getting an error, at least. The error is a 500 internal error. It appears:
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) - it's trying to load wp-content/plugins/vibe-shortcodes/tinymce/popup.php

Answer (score 0):

If you have database access, search the wp_options table for values that have the subfolder in it ( `LIKE '%SUBFOLDER%'` ) to be sure you updated all entries (look for URLs as well as server directory structure paths).

If that doesn't work, check to see if you can recognize additional folders created by the plugin, and do some similar database searching.

Comment: Hello, Adam. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hello, Adam. Thanks for your help.
Anyway, I've made a search in my DB and I found only records with my subfolder inside wp_posts table. But it's in guid field and, considering what I researched, I shouldn't change it.
I took a look at my ftp structure and everything looks fine there too :/

I got just one clue now that just kind of confirm what I was thinking. The page that appears when I try to load the plugin is the same page that appears when I try to access a page that doesn't exist. I think I still have some trouble with the path for this plugin.